# How to calculate the 3d intersection between a ray and the surface defined by the generalized barycentric coordinates of a polygon?

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry

I have a 3d ray defined by a ray position and direction. I also have a 3d polygon defined by N 3d points in space. How can I calculate the 3d intersection between the ray and the surface defined by the generalized barycentric coordinates of the 3d polygon?

The polygon is non planar.